How to repair broken traces of USB B connector for midi keyboard

I changed the USB B connector but I made a mistake and put to much heat around the 4 pins on the connectors pads. Now I do not know how to connect the data pins so that my computer can detect the keyboard. This board is for a Samson Carbon 49
